# Error processing filename containing ampersand in a (Windows shell script) for loop?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm using a for loop in a Windows shell script to recursively process all files on a drive...

```
for /r %src_drv% %%f in (*.*) do call :SUB1 "%%f"
```

Then...

```
:SUB1
echo Breakpoint 10 SUB1 - passed param = %1
set srcfile="%1"
echo Breakpoint 11 - srcfile = %srcfile%
```

Breakpoint 10 echoes the source filename as it should.
Breakpoint 11 fails, treating everything after the "&" as a command.

I tried doing

```
set srcfile=%srcfile:&=^&%
and
set srcfile=%srcfile:^&=^^&%
```

but neither of those work. What's the right way to do this?

Comment: `set "srcFile=%~1"` and use delayed expansion, `echo Breakpoint11 !srcFile!`

Comment: Put quotes around the echoed string, like `echo Breakpoint 11 - srcfile = "%srcfile%"` (this works when there are no quotes in the string, which can be assumed here since it is a file name). If you do not want quotes and also do not want delayed expansion, you need to double-escape the ampersand by `set srcfile=%srcfile:&=^^^&%` (once for this piece of code, and once for `echo` then), or, even better, you use the quoted `set` syntax to spare one level of escaping, `set "srcfile=%srcfile:&=^&%"`…

Comment: I need to expand a little on my original question. While jeb's answer did give me a working variable (!srcfile!), when I try to set destpath to the path (using %~p1) and filename to the filename (using %~nx1), if either of those have an ampersand in them, the xcopy and fc commands both fail.

Comment: Then you are not coding it correctly and you probably are not quoting the file paths correctly. If you change the code then you need to edit your question and update it accordingly. We cannot help you unless you provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example.

Comment: You're absolutely right, Squashman. I applied jeb's fix to my other vars, made sure I was quoting everything right and now it's working.